# How to prevent re-rendering in functional component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

When I run this home page component is rendering many number of times. How to stop this unnecessary rendering. Please help me to solve this problem. Since we dont have ShouldComponentUpdate in functional component how to handle this problem. If possible send me live code example

```
const Home = (props) => {

  const [conversations,setConversations]=useState([]);
  const dispatch=useDispatch();
  const auth=useSelector(state=>state.auth);
  const conv=useSelector(state=>state.conversations);

  console.log(auth);
  

  useEffect(()=>{
    dispatch(getConversations(auth.user._id));
    setConversations(conv.conversations);
  },[auth,conv]);
  return(
    <>
    <Layout />
        <div className="messenger">
          <div className="chatMenu">
            <div className="chatMenuWrapper">
              <input placeholder="Search for friends" className="chatMenuInput"/>
              {
                conversations.map((c)=>{return <Conversations/>})
              }
              
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="chatBox">
            <div className="chatBoxWrapper">
              <div className="chatBoxTop">
                <Message/>
                <Message own={true}/>
                <Message/>
                
              </div>
              <div className="chatBoxBottom">
                <textarea className="chatMessageInput" placeholder="write something"> 
                </textarea>
                <button className="chatSubmitButton">Send</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="chatOnline">
            <div className="chatOnlineWrapper">
              <ChatOnline/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
     </>
   )

 }

export default Home;
```

Comment: `getConversations` modifies `conv`?

Comment: React components rerender when their parent tree is rerendered. Also, console log in function body isn't an accurate measure of when the component is rerendered, use `useEffect` for that. Is there an issue or problem when this component rerenders? Why are you trying to prevent renders? If you really need to try to prevent renders, you can use the [memo HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

Comment: It is not creating any problem but just for optimization and performance of application

Comment: Generally speaking, if there isn't a rendering issue then don't prematurely optimize. React is optimized pretty well out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1):

Best explanation here - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

If you update a State Hook to the same value as the current state, React will bail out without rendering the children or firing effects. (React uses the Object.is comparison algorithm.)

Note that React may still need to render that specific component again before bailing out. That shouldn’t be a concern because React won’t unnecessarily go “deeper” into the tree. If you’re doing expensive calculations while rendering, you can optimize them with useMemo.